# Make a postfix operator with suppressable spacing?

Tags: math-mode, spacing, amsmath

I would like to create a postfix unary operator that normally leaves `\medmuskip` between the operand and postfix operator.  It's easy enough to do this using, for example,

```
\newcommand*{\true}{\mskip\medmuskip\mathsf{true}}
```

so that `x$A \true x$x` yields [image]

However, the extra twist is that I would like to use a group to suppress the spacing, just as is possible for binary operators (such as `\otimes`).  In other words, `x$A{\true}x$x` should yield [image].  Bonus points for making `x$\true$x` (note the absence of `{}`) yield [image].

Here is a skeleton to play with:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\newcommand*{\true}{\mskip\medmuskip\mathsf{true}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
\verb#x$A \true x$x#  & x$A \true x$x \\
\verb#x$A{\true}x$x# & x$A{\true}x$x \\
\verb#x$\true$x#    & x$\true$x
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: What do you think to use `\DeclareMathOperator{\true}{true}` or `\DeclareMathOperator{\true}{\medspace true}`.

Comment: @Sigur This inserts `\thinmuskip`, not `\medmuskip`

Comment: Yes, this is almost, but not quite, what I am looking for.  If I use `\DeclareMathOperator` and write `x$A \true x$x`, I get a space after the operator, i.e., it acts as a binary operator.  I've edited my question to clarify what I am after.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\newcommand*{\true}{\relax\ifnum\lastnodetype>0 \mskip\medmuskip\fi\mathsf{true}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
\verb#x$A \true$x#  & x$A \true$x \\
\verb#x$A{\true}$x# & x$A{\true}$x \\
\verb#x$\true$x#    & x$\true$x
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, this does just what I am looking for!  I'd like to understand how this solution works, though.  Could you add an explanation of `\lastnodetype` (or point me to a reference) and why `\relax` is needed?

Comment: it's an etex extension (so texdoc etex page 7 has the details) it tells you something about the previous thing on the curent list `{}` starts a new list and if you are at the start of a list it is -1 it would be 11 for glue or 15 for a math node etc  you need \relax (or make \true robust) to stop bad expansion in a table cell when tex is looking for \omit (\multicolumn)

Comment: @HenryDeYoung Watch out that `$\left(\true\right)` will insert the space, but I think that you don't need such a strange concoction. Other than this, it's a very clever answer and I don't think one can do better (without LuaTeX).

Comment: Yes You need explicit `{}` as in `$\left({\true}\right) ` to zap the space unfortunately almost all math constructs show as 15 so you can not distinguish the mathopen form \left(